# $geoIntersects does not work when there is self intersect

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I below scenario i am getting perfect result for mongo $geoIntersec query
[image]

But for below scenario where I am not getting result correct result in Mongo DB $geoIntersect query
[image]

I think mongo does not allow self intersetion which is indecated in image in red color.

Is there any other way to get result?

Comment: Can't zoom in enough on geojsonlint.com, but at a glance these don't appear to "intersect" and actually appear to be "adjoining" just outside each others boundries. Could be wrong as I have not checked the adjoining line as yet

Comment: I am helping you. The first line in the [`$geoIntersects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/) documentation *"Selects documents whose geospatial data intersects with a specified GeoJSON object; i.e. where the intersection of the data and the specified object is **non-empty**."* The two shapes share a common "boundary" on the first three vertices, however there is **no area** to a line on the same boundary. So this is not considered an "intersection". Query does exactly what it should.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Even I tried with other shape which is intersecting. But no result.

Comment: You won't get a result. What I've told you twice is **"these do not intersect"**. The shapes to not "cross each other", therefore **no result**. Drawing one shape does not matter. The other one simply does not "cross it".

Comment: @PravinkumarPutta please edit the question to have all the details needed to answer it, rather than posting code into the comments.

Comment: Can any one help for above problem?

Comment: Same issue for me, anyone ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62195561/mongodb-geojson-geointersects-problems

Answer (score 2):

According to mongodb documentation it does not support intersecting polygons. What it supports are these

1. Polygons with a Single Ring
2. Polygons with Multiple Rings
3. MultiPolygon

Kindly refer to [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#polygon) in case you need to know more

Comment: Put simply, your left hand polygon is invalid so you can not carry out operations on (or involving) it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes Mongodb does not allow self-intersecting polygons. you can store them. but wont be able to perform any spatial indexing on them, or use $geointersects etc. You need to resolve the polygons first. There is a npm module for this [turf-kinks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/turf-kinks)