# MongoDB / Geojson $geointersects problems

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geojson

It's been now 8 hours I'm trying to deal with a MongoDB Geojson $geoIntersects issue :

It's working very well when my polygon is a square, or a rectangle,
but I'm unable to get some results from a $geoIntersects request when my Polygon has crossing vertices, like this example :

[image]

(Image from (https://geoman.io/geojson-editor))

The polygon data looks like this :

```
{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "shape": "Polygon"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [-1.565584, 47.226352],
                    [-1.564704, 47.226927],
                    [-1.564093, 47.225616],
                    [-1.563138, 47.226374],
                    [-1.565584, 47.226352]
                ]
            ]
        },
        "id": "dda54a42-090b-46ea-9dd0-fdda6d240f90"
    }
```

For this example, I need to know if the Polygon includes my Point coordinates.
This is my simple query :

```
db.geojsondatas.find({
    geometry: {
        $geoIntersects: {
            $geometry: {
                type: "Point",
                coordinates: [ -1.555638, 47.216245 ]
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone knows if there is a way to do this ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try with [JTS Topology Suite](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/locationtech.jts) and investigate your polygon:

[image]

I don't think `$geoIntersects` supports Self-intersecting polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you're right, $geoIntersects does not supports self-Intersecting Polygon :(
I'm now looking for a solution to split them in two.. Thanks again.